# Elastic Beanstalk could not find any platforms

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-iam

I'm trying to deploy my django app via amazon Elastic BeanStalk(using this [tutorial](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_Python_django.html)), but getting the following error.

**ERROR: Elastic Beanstalk could not find any platforms. Ensure you have the necessary permissions to access Elastic Beanstalk.**

[image]

How can i fix this issue?

Thanks!

Comment: what do you get when you run `aws elasticbeanstalk list-available-solution-stacks` ?

Comment: No command 'aws' found.

Do i have to install any other package?

Comment: yup. please install http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/installing.html  
 - when done, run the above command and you'll see what permissions you have

Comment: Tal's hint worked for me, basically I found there was no AWS CLI configuration. More [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-getting-started.html).

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Problem is, as @helloV said, your user does not have access. Now **this was a complete surprise to me because I was using the root** (which I really shouldn't) and I ASSUMED it would just have access.

So solution is that you HAVE TO ATTACH a policy as shown in the screenshot below since even the root IAM account does not have this policy.

[image]

Comment: Right answer! Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

Your IAM account does not have permission to access Elastic Beanstalk. Contact your IAM admin and have the admin grant your account full Elastic Beanstalk permissions.

Comment: I enabled Elastic BeanStalk full access in IAM Role Policy, still not working...:(

Comment: @KrishnaAnaril run `eb init --debug` and show us the result.

Comment: @NickHumrich  2016-04-23 22:31:13,463 (DEBUG) ebcli.lib.aws : Making api call: (elasticbeanstalk, list_available_solution_stacks) to region: us-west-2 with args:{}
2016-04-23 22:31:14,576 (DEBUG) ebcli.lib.aws : API call finished, status = 200
2016-04-23 22:31:14,577 (DEBUG) ebcli.lib.aws : Response: {u'SolutionStacks': [], 'ResponseMetadata': {'date': 'Sun, 24 Apr 2016 02:31:12 GMT', 'HTTPStatusCode': 200, 'RequestId': '9d0b44a4-09c4-11e6-b024-ab912e86d319'}, u'SolutionStackDetails': []}
2016-04-23 22:31:14,577 (DEBUG) ebcli.lib.elasticbeanstalk : Solution Stack result size = 0

Comment: @mark are you sure you have the correct permissions, and you are using the correct credentials?

Comment: @NickHumrich My apologies. I had two different profiles on my machine and failed to realize what one was default.

Answer (score 5):

I had this issue as well. There is a file in /Users/USER_NAME/.aws/ called config.

It looks like below -

```
[profile eb-cli]
aws_access_key_id = <ACCESS_KEY>
aws_secret_access_key = <SECRET_ACCESS_KEY>
```

Update this file with your updated aws_access_key_id & aws_secret_access_key

Credit: [How to change the AWS account using the Elastic Beanstalk CLI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29190202/how-to-change-the-aws-account-using-the-elastic-beanstalk-cli)

Comment: Yes, this applies to the situation where I accidentally entered the wrong credentials first.

Answer (score 1):

`rm ~/.aws`

This fixed the issue for me (updating `~/.aws/config` or `~/.aws/credentials` in here didn't help)

Answer (score 0):

Not much of an answer, but I'll leave it here for anyone else so they don't frustrate themselves debugging an issue that doesn't require debugging.

IAM permissions don't seem to always provision immediately, & even when they do sometimes the CLI doesn't seem to pick this up right away (would welcome any technical expansion on why this is).

In my case, I ensured that my IAM user had the permission **AWSElastikBeanstalkFullAccess**. Running `eb init` was still prompting `ERROR: NotFoundError - Elastic Beanstalk could not find any platforms. Ensure you have the necessary permissions to access Elastic Beanstalk.`

Fighting with this did nothing, after about 5 minutes I ran again and all was well. Next I run `eb create` to create an environment. Same issue. I gave it about another 5 minutes, tried again, and all was well.

I can't expand on why this is, but I wanted to make sure my experience was documented here so future readers don't tear their hair out fighting a permissions error when they have proper permissions.