# How to change the AWS account using the Elastic Beanstalk CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I deployed an app using elastic beanstalk to my personal AWS account..Now I want to change the AWS credentials so the eb cli knows to deploy to a different account. But it does not ask me for the AWS keys when I type "eb init". Where do I specify this?

Comment: is `AWS_CREDENTIAL_FILE` set?

Answer (score 155, accepted):

I had to add a new profile to this file `~/.aws/config`. Example of the file with 2 profiles:

```
[profile eb-cli]
aws_access_key_id = XXXXXXXXXXXXX
aws_secret_access_key = XXXXXXXXXXXX

[profile eb-cli2]
aws_access_key_id = XXXXXXXXXX
aws_secret_access_key = XXXXXXXXXXXX
```

Also make sure to update the profile value in your application .elasticbeanstalk/config.yml

To init using the new profile, use:

```
eb init --profile [profilename]
```

Comment: I wasn't able to edit the profile value in the  .elasticbeanstalk/config.yml file.  Going to the directory and then running the command with the --profile flag allowed met the profile value to be used.  `eb init --profile [profilename]`.  I followed the example above and used `eb init --profile eb-cli2`.

Comment: Yup, just creating a new profile and running ```eb init``` actually *changes it back* to whatever the first/original profile was. The ```--profile``` flag was the key for me.

Comment: If anyone encounters an error "ERROR: NotFoundError - Elastic Beanstalk could not find any platforms. Ensure you have the necessary permissions to access Elastic Beanstalk.", make sure to navigate to IAM > Users on aws dashboard, select your user, and Attach the Policy "AWSElasticBeanstalkFullAccess". Cheers

Comment: I think the path should be:  ~/.aws/config not .yaml
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27514937/aws-eb-cli-3-sets-up-application-for-wrong-account

Comment: After I did everything here including @EderYif answer it keeps asking "Do you wish to continue with CodeCommit?" and "Do you want to set up SSH for your instances?" and nothing of responses works :(

Comment: I couldn't find the file on Windows. it is located on C:\Users\USERNAME\.aws\config 
[docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb-cli3-configuration.html)

Comment: Thanks, man @Random5000.
But I need to write --profile profile-name at the end of each line. Can you specify how to use profile-name as default rather than writing ```--profile profile-name``` at the end of each code?

Comment: Don't skip the "Also make sure to update the profile value in your application .elasticbeanstalk/config.yml", if you skip, it doesn't work :)

Answer (score 43):

Bpn's answer is correct just add the next step to avoid spending time as I did..

After updating the `~/.aws/config` file, just run:

```
eb init --profile <profilename>
```

in order to switch between the account.

(in this case profilename = eb-cli2)

Answer (score 4):

Using `export AWS_EB_PROFILE="default"` I was able to use my key from my default profile from `~/.aws/credentials`.

For more details: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb-cli3-configuration.html

Answer (score 2):

The `awsebcli` tool automatically creates a file named `~/.aws/config` and you can see your keys in there under the `[profile eb-cli]` category. Just change them there.

```
[profile eb-cli]
aws_access_key_id = ...
aws_secret_access_key = ...
```

Comment: My tech lead set me up with AWS IAM user with limited access. After I installed awsebcli, I was able to find my `~/.aws/config`. It loaded my profiles from my other accounts, but I don't seem to have a new `aws_access_key_id` and `aws_secret_access_key` for my IAM user account. Can I generate one or does my Tech lead need to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Specify the profiles in ~/.aws/credentials:

```
[myprofile2] 
aws_access_key_id = ...
aws_secret_access_key = ...
```

Like other has indicated. Then use it in eb cli like this:

```
eb init --profile myprofile2
```

Basically append "--profile myprofile2" in all eb commands:

```
eb deploy --profile myprofile2 
eb open --profile myprofile2
```

Answer (score -1):

I would agree with the other answers that using an aws profile is the way to go, but another way to accomplish this if you want to run a one off command without creating an aws profile you can do

```
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=**** AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=**** eb <command>
```